Grail, GORM, Spock: An association from the table [X] refers to an unmapped class: [Y]
I'm getting this error in a Spock test after adding a new association to one of the domain objects that this service uses. I haven't found any Grails-related or GORM-related questions referencing this Exception.  Everything I can find is using Hibernate directly and is 5+ years old.
An association from the table classification refers to an unmapped class: com.myCompany.Classifier

Here's the test class
package com.myCompany

import grails.test.hibernate.HibernateSpec
import grails.testing.gorm.DataTest
import grails.testing.services.ServiceUnitTest

class StatusQueueServiceSpec extends HibernateSpec implements ServiceUnitTest<StatusQueueService>, DataTest {

    def setup() {
        ...
    }

    void "test handleStatusChange"() {
        ...
    }
}

Here is the Classifier domain object
package com.myCompany

import grails.compiler.GrailsCompileStatic
import grails.plugins.orm.auditable.Auditable
import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode
import groovy.transform.ToString

import static com.myCompany.ClassifierType.SAGEMAKER

@GrailsCompileStatic
@EqualsAndHashCode(includes = 'name')
@ToString(includes = 'name', includeNames = true, includePackage = false)
class Classifier implements DomainClass, Auditable {

    String name
    ClassifierType classifierType = SAGEMAKER
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated

    static constraints = {
        name nullable: false, blank: false, maxSize: 256, unique: true
        classifierType nullable: false, blank: false
    }
}

Here's the Classification domain object
package com.myCompany

import groovy.transform.ToString
import org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.ConnectionSource

@ToString(includeNames = true, includePackage = false, includes = ['photo', 'classifier', 'score'])
class Classification implements DomainClass {

    static String GOOD = 'GOOD'
    static String BAD = 'BAD'
    static String MAYBE = 'MAYBE'
    static String UNCLASSIFIED = 'UNCLASSIFIED'

    float score
    PhotoRequirement photoRequirement
    Classifier classifier
    Photo photo

    static belongsTo = [PhotoRequirement]

    static constraints = {
        score nullable: false
        photoRequirement nullable: true, unique: 'photo'
        classifier nullable: true
        photo nullable: false
    }

    static mapping = {
        datasources([ConnectionSource.DEFAULT, 'readReplica'])
    }
}


The problem was that I was extending HibernateSpec rather than Specification.
import spock.lang.Specification

class StatusQueueServiceSpec extends Specification implements ServiceUnitTest<StatusQueueService>, DataTest {

